# Add image and text into a video using ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I would like a help. I am creating a video editing ionic application where I want to edit video by adding image and text into the video and make it downloadable.

So how can I achieved this in the application?

Comment: You have to use any Video Editing Tool to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic and cordova does not provide such as useful functionality officially. I searched everywhere but in the result i just found this paid link sdk. [Learn how to get started with the VideoEditor SDK & Ionic and how to swiftly integrate the SDK into an Ionic application with this Quick Start.](https://img.ly/docs/vesdk/quickstarts/ionic/)

Comment: if someone knows about free tool to use in ionic 5 then share with me. thanks in advance

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.